# Custom Bibliography - missing random commas, unwanted abbreviated author lists, and section title

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to create a custom bibliography for the NAWEA windtech conference, and I've almost got it. I'm using `biblatex` (but I'm open to any solution). The citations must be numbered, and in the reference section they should follow the following format:

**References**

1. Last, F. and Last, F., Year: *Title*, Journal. pp. #-#.

Shown below is my current attempt, which works pretty well, I'm only missing a couple of things:

- the comma after the title for some of the items
- The authors shouldn't be abbreviated to et. al.
- I need to get rid of or change the References title (It should just be `\textbf{References}`, and aligned with the normal text.)
- I need to get rid of all the editions, and volumes.

```
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric, bibstyle=ext-authoryear,dashed=false, sorting=none, giveninits=true, isbn=false, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1} 
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given} 
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} 
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}  
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 


\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}} 
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography} 
  {\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item}
```

I'm using Overleaf if that changes anything.

[image: current status of my bibliography]

EDIT: I found a quick solution to getting rid of the edition, volume, and number:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{edition} \clearfield{volume} \clearfield{number}}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Just to let you know that this was very helpful, as I am still not able to upvote/comment!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I finally found the answers to my questions. Some of them are kind of hacky, but eh, it worked:

- the comma after the title for some of the items.

Change `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` to `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\addcomma}}`. Also, remove random periods in the bib file.

- The authors shouldn't be abbreviated to et. al.

Add `maxnames=somenumber` to the package options.

- I need to get rid of or change the References title (It should just be \textbf{References}, and aligned with the normal text.)

Change `\printbibliography` to

```
\textbf{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

- I need to get rid of all the editions, and volumes.

Add `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{edition} \clearfield{volume} \clearfield{number}}` to the preamble.